# How to get video length and get video state using the VLC web plugin

Tags: javascript, video, plugins, web, vlc

I'm beginner on use vlc web plugin, so I have a problem in my code and I don't know how to solve.

I play a video on browser using the VLC web plugin, but I need to get the length of the video and then close the browser when the video is finished.

To know the video length, I used the "**get_length()**" function, but when the returned value is printed, it is undefined.

To know if the video is playing, I used the "**isPlaying()**" function, but when the returned value is printed, it is undefined.

I'm using these functions in the wrong way? I need to parse the returned value?

Below is my code commented:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>First Video</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
         id="vlcp"
         autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="400" height="300" toolbar="true"
         target="/home/juliano/Documentos/Dados/web/educacao.flv" />
</br>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" TYPE="text/javascript">

var vlc = document.getElementById("vlcp");

//In this point I get plugin version
var version=vlc.versionInfo();
document.write ("<br>The plugin version is: "+version);

//In this point I try to get video length
var length=vlc.video.get_length();
document.write ("<br>The video length is: "+length);

//In this point I try to get video state
var state=vlc.isplaying();
if(state=="true")
  document.write ("<br>The video is playing, and the state value is: "+state);
else
  document.write ("<br>The video is not playing, and the state value is: "+state);  

</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 0):

to get the length of video use:`vlc.input.length`: length of the input file in number of milliseconds. 0 is returned for 'live' streams or clips whose length cannot be determined by VLC. It returns -1 if no input is playing.

`vlc.playlist.isPlaying`: a boolean that returns true if the current playlist item is playing and false when it is not playing

read here:https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

Answer (score 0):

**PlayList Object** required.

Use

```
vlc.playlist.isPlaying() //a boolean that returns true if the current playlist item is playing and false when it is not playing
```

Instead of

```
vlc.isplaying();
```